# to_csv returns special characters when writing pandas dataframe into csv

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

When trying to write a pandas dataframe into a csv file, I noticed that special characters,

e.g., the input data from Excel shows "Department - Reconciliation", after writing into csv, instead of "Department - Reconciliation" it shows "Department â€“ Reconciliation". But when I read the csv file into Python, it shows "Department - Reconciliation" again.

I used `df.to_csv('df.csv', index = False )`

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

---

other attempts:

tried 1:

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', index = False, encoding="utf-8")
```

and 2:

```
df = df.astype(str)
df = df.applymap(str)
```

in hope to convert data type into string but the results are the same.

---

Edit:

The source data has been extracted from a business system, I just noticed that it shows "Department - Reconciliation" in the `Excel` file but "Department â€“ Reconciliation" in the `csv` file.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? If windows, what's your code page (the `chcp` command may help). When you say "it shows", what shows, exactly? Did you read it into excel? Or maybe a text editor?

Comment: Hey @tdelaney yes I'm running on windows, please see edited question. I'll have a look at `chcp` command, thanks

Comment: try df.to_csv('df.csv', index = False, encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Hi @XiaominWu yeah I tried that and it didn't work, but thanks

Comment: You've extracted from excel, written to csv and displayed it somehow. These can all be events where encoding gets messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use 'utf_8_sig' instead of 'utf-8'

---

`utf-8` uses bytes as the encoding unit; its byte order is the same in all systems. There is no byte order problem, so it does not require BOM (Byte Order Mark), so when reading with `utf-8` encoding, fetching a file with a BOM, it will treat the BOM as the file's content, and an error similar to the above will occur. `utf-8-sig` is *"utf-8 with signature"*, meaning UTF with BOM in windows 10. So when `utf-8-sig` reads a utf-8 file with BOM, it will make BOM process separately and be isolated from the text content, which is also our expected result.

Comment: Could you please add a few words explaining why this is so?

Comment: "utf-8" uses bytes as the encoding unit; its byte order is the same in all systems. There is no byte order problem, so it does not require BOM (Byte Order Mark). When reading with "utf-8" encoding, fetching a file with a BOM, it will be treated as the file's content, and an error similar to the above will occur.

"utf-8-sig" is "utf-8 with signature, " meaning utf with BOM in windows 10. So when "utf-8-sig" reads a "utf-8 file with BOM, it will make BOM process separately and be isolated from the text content, which is also our expected result.